# praw: Get body and title of random post in subreddit

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to print out the title along with the content (body) of a random post on a given subreddit. I've been looking around all over the internet on how to do this, but I cant seem to figure it out.

I've written something down here that gets the id of a random submission.

```py
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id = "",
    client_secret = "",
    password = "",
    user_agent = "",
    username = "",
)

random_submission = reddit.subreddit('playboicarti').random()

print(random_submission)
```

Example output:

```
v206wo
```

Here it's getting the id of a random submission from the subreddit called `playboicarti`.

Does anyone know how I'm supposed to print out the title and the content of that submission using the id?

Answer (score 2):

You can access both the `title` attributes and the `url` attributes, print the title and open the url in a browser perhaps?

```
import webbrowser 
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id = "",
    client_secret = "",
    password = "",
    user_agent = "",
    username = "",
)

random_submission = reddit.subreddit('playboicarti').random()
print(random_submission.title)
webbrowser.open(random_submission.url)
```

The nice thing about the `url` attribute is that it will follow the link, or open the post in the case of a self/text post.

If you wanted to print the context of a text post OR open a link post, you can access the `selftext` attribute, or open the link like so:

```
import webbrowser
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id = "",
    client_secret = "",
    password = "",
    user_agent = "",
    username = "",
)

random_submission = reddit.subreddit('playboicarti').random()
print(random_submission.title)

if random_submission.selftext:
    print(random_submission.selftext)
else:
    # a link post will return a blank string ('falsy'), so open the link
    webbrowser.open(random_submission.url)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without the use of Selenium?

Comment: `webbrowser` is probably simpler to use since it's standard

Comment: please see if my edit works for your use case